# Pay with credit card test in stripe

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments

Hi everyone I am using Stripe in my website with Wordpress and Woocomerce.

I install and configure Stripe like the document say, to use the credit card of test.  But I obtain this error

"Please enter your card details to make a payment. Developers: Please make sure that you are including jQuery and there are no JavaScript errors on the page."

I obtain a error in the javascript file

```
wc_stripe_form.form.block is not a function
```

the error is  here

```
block: function() {
        wc_stripe_form.form.block({
            message: null,
            overlayCSS: {
                background: '#fff',
                opacity: 0.6
            }
        });
    }
```

Anyone has the same error when try to pay with a credit car test.

Thanks in advice!

Comment: jQuery is enqueued by WooCommerce itself. So unless your theme doesn't have a `wp_head()` and a `wp_footer()` then it should be getting loaded. Therefore you need to do as the error instructs and make sure that you do not have any JavaScript errors on the page. Check your browser's developer console.

Comment: Thanks @helgatheviking but I don't have any error in JS and I have head and footer. I obtain the JS error when I place my order. Any idea!!

Comment: You can also try enabling [`WP_DEBUG`](https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) and specifically `WP_DEBUG_LOG` and see if that gets you more specific error messages. Right now there's just now way for us to know what is going on with your specific set up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue. I was including jQuery 2.2 in my custom theme. I downgraded that to 1.12.4 and it fixed the issue.

Comment: I faced same problem, And i also downgrade jquery version and problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I found out that jQuery was enqueued twice so I just removed the other one and that fixed it.